# mysql: update record, row for row

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of table:

```
+----+-----------+----------+------+
| id | id_master | id_slave | temp |
+----+-----------+----------+------+
|  1 |        12 | 55       |   45 |
|  2 |        12 | 56       |   50 |
|  3 |         4 | NULL     |   44 |
|  4 |         5 | NULL     |   41 |
|  5 |         2 | 51       |   37 |
+----+-----------+----------+------+
```

How you can see, some `id_slave` are `NULL` . I need to update them, with corresponding `id_master` value.

For example, final table need to be:

```
+----+-----------+----------+------+
| id | id_master | id_slave | temp |
+----+-----------+----------+------+
|  1 |        12 |       55 |   45 |
|  2 |        12 |       56 |   50 |
|  3 |         4 |        4 |   44 |
|  4 |         5 |        5 |   41 |
|  5 |         2 |       51 |   37 |
+----+-----------+----------+------+
```

Basically, I need to UPDATE table SET id_slave = id_master WHERE id_slave IS NULL.

My tempting is:

```
UPDATE my_table SET id_slave = id_master WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id_slave IS NULL)
```

But error is:

```
You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause
```

Thank you for your support

Comment: Try `UPDATE my_table SET id_slave = id_master WHERE id_slave IS NULL`. You seem to have the exact same line your question itself :)

Comment: _Basically, I need to UPDATE table SET id_slave = id_master WHERE id_slave IS NULL._ That query is perfectly alright. Why do you need to do it the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have it in your question:

```
update my_table
set id_slave = id_master 
where id_slave is null
```